# JQUERY AJAX LOAD-TEXTBOX FOCUS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to get the text in a div to show when the textbox beside the div is focused on. I am not seeing that text

Below is the jquery script

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //$jquery selector
            //find textbox and place it in a variable
            var txtbox = $('input[type="text"]');

            //when textbox recives focus
            txtbox.focus(function () {
                $('#newroleHelpDiv').load('help.html');
            });

            //when textbox loses focus
            txtbox.blur(function () {
                $('#newroleHelpDiv').html('');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Below is the ASP code

```
    <fieldset style="width:350px">
            <legend> New Role</legend>
             <table>
                 <tr>
                     <td>Insert New Role:</td>
                     <td> <input type="text" id="newrole" /> </td>
                     <td> <div id="newroleHelpDiv" runat="server"></div></td>
                     </tr>
                 </table>
        </fieldset>
</asp:Content>
```

Below is the help.html file where the help text is coming from

```
<div id="newroleHelpDiv">
    You may add an employee to this role
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` should be unique so if you have `id="newroleHelpDiv"` main html, you should use another id for your `help.html`

not sure if you could load the html file, but if loaded it only once, then you can show and hide like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#newroleHelpDiv').load('help.html');
  $('#newroleHelpDiv').hide();
  //$jquery selector
  //find textbox and place it in a variable
  var txtbox = $('input[type="text"]');

  //when textbox recives focus
  txtbox.focus(function() {
    $('#newroleHelpDiv').show();
  });

  //when textbox loses focus
  txtbox.blur(function() {
    $('#newroleHelpDiv').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset style="width:350px">
  <legend> New Role</legend>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Insert New Role:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="newrole" /> </td>
      <td>
        <div id="newroleHelpDiv" runat="server">You may add an employee to this role</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Tried those but it does not work. Could it be that it's not showing because Im trying to load help.html on a .aspx page?

Comment: @A.Ban are you able to load the html at least?

Comment: I am able to view it in a browser yes

Comment: @A.Ban have you changed the `id="newroleHelpDiv"` in your help.html? since id must be unique

Comment: @A.Ban or might be the path? could it be like `/help.html` or `xxx/help.html`?